# Error 500 when deploying site from localhost to IIS

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp.net-web-api2, web-deployment

I finally want to deploy my asp.net WebApi to IIS 10.
The site works flawless on localhost, but as soon as I try to do anything Database related, I get an Internal Server Error (500).

I checked the connectionstring and it seems to be correct.
I added a user for Domain\MachineName$ on SQL Server.

my connectionstring:

```
<add name="myDB" connectionString="data source=correctserver;initial catalog=correctdatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

one of the failing requests:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('GET', hostedserverurl + '/v1/correctapicall/' + correctrequestparameter, true)
```

Error happens here:

```
request.send()
```

Expected result: the same as from localhost, JSON if using direct API call.
Actual result:
Errormessage: ("Fehler" is german for "Error")

```
{"Message":"Fehler"}
```

I spent quite some time on this and now I'm on the finish line. But it seems it's more a finish wall...
What do I need to configure? I did not setup anything special.

EDIT:
After enabling more extensive error messages with the help of the webconfig, I was able to get to this inner exception:

```
"ExceptionMessage": "Die SELECT-Berechtigung wurde für das __MigrationHistory-Objekt, correctdatabase-Datenbank, dbo-Schema, verweigert.",
      "ExceptionType": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
```

This leads me to believe this is a user priviledge related thing... But I already created a user for the IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I get this every time I copy the production database, rename it to be my dev database and forget to add my dev user to the new dev db - the very first thing that EF tries to do (when you carry out any database action) is establish the existence/setup the migrationhistory table - if the user it's using doesn't have the privileges or doesn't exist, an error like this occurs

Ensure that the login/user pair the application pool is running under, exists in the database. If your IIS App Pool is called Wiggle, then you'll need to create a login/user pair for [IIS APPPOOL\Wiggle] inside the DB and ensure that that user has rights to create tables, perform all CRUD operations etc

You can see which app pool your site is using in IIS Manager; select the site, and click basic settings in the top right

ps; if this still isn't working out, you should post up some screenshots of the config pages where you have set up your site, your site's app pool (and the local identity it uses), and your SQL server user. Don't obscure them like I have here, because we need to see them to check what they're set to:

#### Website settings:

[image]

#### App pool settings:

[image]

#### SQLS settings:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I fail at Step1: actually creating the user. I do NOT click the search button, I just right click on Okay.
Error 15401

Comment: You said `I added a user for Domain\MachineName$ on SQL Server.` but that might not be the username sql server sees when the production server attempts to log in. When using integrated security SQLS will see a username relating to the account credential of the application pool running the site. Because these things can be configured in a variety of ways we really need to see images of your setup to help further. I'm also confused by your assertion that right clicking an OK button does something;are your mouse buttons swapped over?Right clicking a button typically does nothing in my experience